# How am I able to modify an object attribute inside a function which is not even inside that class

Tags: python-3.x

```py
class foo:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x  = x
foo_obj = foo(4)
def fooo():
    foo_obj.x += 1
fooo()
print(foo_obj)
```

Usually we get a referenced before assingment error if we try to modify a global variable inside a function, but Why am i not getting it here.

Comment: You get a `referenced before assignment` error when you reference the same variable and make it a local one. Here, you reference its attribute. There is no scope-clash. `foo_obj` is well defined when you call the function. Then, you simply access its `x` attribute and change it. Why would there be an error?

Comment: Are you bringing concepts of default private over here to python?

Comment: if you want a private object var use __varName